# Organise site's module

Tags: javascript, jquery, object-oriented

I was wondering about on how to organise the code on my site, to make it clearer as possible and clearly readable.

I'm organising it with `namespace`, separating every single section of the page.

For example:

```
var Header = {
//code relative to the header
}

var CentralBody = {
//code relative to the CentralBody
}

$(function(){
//code to execute on doc ready

});
```

First of all, I would know if it is a good way to organise code. In second instance, I was thinking about "what must be placed where". I explain: If, for example, I have to assign some tooltip or to `bind` event with code like

```
$('someclass').tooltip() 
$('someclass').on( 'event' , ... );
```

where do I have to place this kind of "*functions*"? Do I have to place them in the concerning `namespace`?  Do I have to place them on `document.ready`?  Or writing `functions` in `namespace` and then `call` them on `document.ready`?

Answer (score 2):

A conceptual question, those are always tricky.

Organizing by namespace is not a bad idea, though I would lowercase your namespace ( `Header` -> `header` etc. )

Furthermore, I would suggest to look into [Movel View Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) and let each namespace have a `model`, `view` and `controller`.

The binding of events is in the realm of the controller. So when you initialize the controller, that is where can you do all the binding.

So in `document.ready` you can call `centralBody.init()` which could call `centralBody.controller.init()`.